# ZFS recovery with missing device

Tags: recovery, zfs

what i wanted:

`zfs add poolname cache nvme-partition`.

what i did:

```
zfs add poolname nvme-partition
zfs export poolname
```

device-no-longer-availeable

```
zfs import
```

shows poolname but cannot import

**any idea how to recover the 10 TB of my poolname without the 10 GB of my nvme-partition?**

Comment: `zpool import` without poolname always shows all available importable pools without doing the import (because you specified no name). Do you want to import your pool and this fails; or can you import it but want to remove the wrongly added device?

Comment: sorry for may being unclear: 
zfs import shows the pool but  "all possible" ways using import with any flags and oc the poolname do not succeed:

if i use ZDB -e poolname I see the pool which has 2 children - my 10 TB drive and another child which infos cannot be shown (as there is no ZFS cache file on this machine for this pool)

Comment: so what I need is to know how I can use ZDB i.e. to recover all files found to a given path/device etc. - remember 10.000 GB good data and a few GB on the missing drive.
As ZFS does no "real raid 0" - especially if the drivesd are so unequally set - there _must_ be 90 % of the data still intact!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477044/howto-zdb-e-poolname-to-recover-data-from-a-single-zfs-device

Comment: [I re-wrote my issue on this thread:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477044/howto-zdb-e-poolname-to-recover-data-from-a-single-zfs-device)