# HowTo zdb -e poolname to recover data from a single ZFS device

Tags: recovery, zfs

I have the following situation:

1*10TB Drive, full of data on a ZFS

I wanted to add a 100GB NVME partition as a cache

instead of using `zpool add poolname cache nvmepartion` I wrote `zpool add poolname nvmepartition`

I did **not** see my mistake and exported this pool.

Neither the NVME drive is availeable any more, nor the system has any information about this pool in the ZFS cache (due to export).

current status:

`zpool import` shows the pool but I cannot import the pool using any way found on the internet.

`zdb -e poolname` shows me what i know: the pool, its name, that it (sadly) has 2 children which one is not availeable any more - and that the system has no informatioon about the missing child (so all tricks i found on internet in linked a ghost device etc. wont work either)

> as far i know the only way is to use ZDB to generate all files through
>   the "journal" and pipe/save them to another path.

**

> but how? Nowhere I found any documentation on that.

**

note: the 10 TB drive was 90% full, then I added the NVME partion as a sibling - as ZFS is no real raid 0 and due to the fact that these sibling have been so unequal in size and as I did not wrote many data after my mistake happened - I am quite sure that most of my data is still there.